# Sort collection with binary comparison function in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Is there a way to sort a PowerShell collection providing a custom binary comparison function?
I'm looking for an analogue of C# [Sort(Comparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Comparison__0__) which can be invoked with an instance of delegate [int Comparison(T x, T y)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.comparison-1), or Java's [static Collections.sort(List list, Comparator c)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) where an instance of [interface Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) can be supplied.

BTW: I'm restricted to PowerShell v4.0 with my problem.

**Edit:**
Providing an example collection:

```
$coll = @{
  "A" = @();
  "B" = @("C", "D");
  "C" = @("E");
  "D" = @();
  "E" = @();
  "F" = @()
}
```

My use case requires the list of keys from the hash table `$coll` but ordered in such a way, that no key `$must_follow` occurs before another key `$must_precede` such that `$must_precede -in $coll[$must_follow]`.

An expected order after processing could look like this:

```
$solved = @{
  "A" = @();
  "E" = @();
  "C" = @("E");
  "D" = @();
  "B" = @("C", "D");
  "F" = @()
}
```

Comment: You can use the `Sort-Object` cmdlet using a calculated property that looks ike `@{Expression={my_expression}; Ascending=$true}`. Have a look at examples 5 and 6 of [Sort-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-4.0)

Comment: Can you give us an example of a collection and what comparison you would like it to sort on?

Comment: @Theo thanks. I'm aware of `Sort-Object` cmdlet but it doesn't provide the ability to compare two objects one with another. The expression can only be calculated based on one object at a time, like you assign a score to an object and the output gets sorted based on that score. What I think I need, is the ability to assess, given any two objects `$a` and `$b`, that `$a` must occur before `$b`. I have provided a minimal example of a collection I have to deal with.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think you'd have to make a new type or class, and then define a CompareTo() method for it.  Check out the overload definitions for int's compareto() `(1).CompareTo`.

Comment: @js2010 thanks for hint. That would do the trick indeed. I thought about that, but unfortunately custom classes were introduced in PowerShell v5 and I'm stuck with 4.x for time being. I will have to actually work some on this and busily script the sorting logic myself I'm afraid.

Comment: You could define the class in C# (or other .net language) and bring it in with add-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the constraints mentioned, I didn't find any way to make use of any sort of sorting function. I assume there's no such feature as sorting with binary comparators in PowerShell v4.

I was able to order my list as required using a less fancy solution, more or less like this:

- iterate over $coll entries
- iterate over all items in the entry's value
- recursively call the above check with those values' items corresponding values in $coll
- add the name to $solved if not yet present